# Scan files in a Google Drive folder via an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I would like some help checking how many files are inside a Google Drive folder before allowing a form submission.

I have this form here:
[image]

I would like that when the `Submit` button is clicked, a function checks how many files exist in a `child folder` of the folder where this GAS file is.

The HTML form GAS is linked to this worksheet here:
[image]

After checking how many files there are in the `_` folder I would like to apply the following `if/else` statements:

If the `_` folder has more than `3` files, display a confirmation `pop-up`, if the answer is `Yes`, create any file in the `_` folder, if the answer is `No`, just don't allow the form submission.

If the `_` folder contains `4` or more files, display an error message and disallow form submission.

The code of this HTML form can be seen here, accessing the spreadsheet's GAS:

[HTML Form - Demonstration](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odCFR8_jEnxVDYfQNQx0uVf37uSN5iAJ7ucwwK2OgcY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: No problem, I'll try to explain it another way. The first script presented in the question is a functional script, it works inside a Google Spreadsheet, the `.gs` and `html` scripts presented in the sequence are my last adaptation attempts.

Comment: My goal is to adapt the first script to work in an `HTML form`, this `HTML form` is published in a Web App and can be viewed [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzSBAl0RB_yr-jTrYIJ0OWQK7Xz2uzL0qann7YhMVqopeojga_ox6y20hcsx58Kz7ad/exec). My current code can be viewed in the `GAS` linked to [this worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odCFR8_jEnxVDYfQNQx0uVf37uSN5iAJ7ucwwK2OgcY/edit?usp=sharing). If you still can't understand, please let me know. Thank you very much for your attention and help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? I sincerely apologize that I am trying to understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Tanaike I edited my question and added some pictures, see if you get the point. Basically I need to convert the worksheet function to this HTML form. If you still can't understand it, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot still understand `If the file count is greater than MaximumAmount an error is displayed and the other functions are not executed, but if the count is greater than DailyLimit, a pop-up is opened with the message Do you want to make an increase request?, if the answer is yes, a file is created in the folder.`. I thought that this might be your expected result. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly, this is the expected result of this function, I need it to check the folder `_` and perform these actions. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected result. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and trying to understand. Explaining more directly, I need a function that checks how many files are in the `-` folder when the form is submitted. If there are more than `3` files in that folder, I need a confirmation popup to be displayed, if this popup is confirmed, I need any file to be created inside the `-` folder, if the popup is canceled, the function simply stops all the scripts. If you still can't understand it, please let me know.

Comment: @Tanaike I rephrased my question, see if that way you can understand. If you cannot understand, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I believe your question will be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Solution:

I made some changes on the `getLimitFolder()` function to return the count of the files inside the `_` folder.

```
function getLimitFolder(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pastapai = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  var files = [];
  Logger.log(pastapai);
  //var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getId();
  var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getFiles();
  while(limitfolder.hasNext()){
    var file = limitfolder.next();
    files.push([file.getId()]);
  }
  console.log(files.length);
  return files.length;
}
```

**Inside the folder `_`:**
[image]

From here, since the function can now return the count of files within the `_` folder, you may need to create a new modal window on your HTML file to display the message first and create a separate function to determine the conditions for your if else statement.

Comment: Do not add code / logs as images.

Comment: @Century Tuna Thank you very much for your help and patience! This will help me a lot, I haven't been able to test it yet, but as soon as possible I'll get back to you about the result.

Comment: @Century Tuna I did some tests and it seems that the function is correctly returning the number of files in the folder, so I created the HTML modal, the functions referring to it and the If/Else statements, but when I try to submit the form, a blank page opens. Could you take a look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong? You can view it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odCFR8_jEnxVDYfQNQx0uVf37uSN5iAJ7ucwwK2OgcY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Century Tuna I managed to get it working the way you suggested. Now the popup appears and obeys the If/Else statements, but for some reason it always opens a second white window when clicking on any button in the popup, can you tell me why this is happening? Thank you very much for your help and attention!